# java - unqualified access to field - this

Tags: java, this

I am working on a java project on Eclipse on win 7.

Now, I was working on the same project before on a different eclipse version on Linux.  So while working on the Linux system all was fine.  All of the sudden when I transferred the project to the win 7 computer, every place that I refer to one of the constructors data members, the compiler gives a warning that

> unqualified access to field

If I add "this._member", then it is fine.

Why do I need to add this and why didn't the compiler give me a warning before?

```
  public class SoundWave {

     private  int _sr ;

     public SoundWave (int sr){

      _sr = sr ;
     }

    }
```

Comment: What compiler version is eclipse using to compiler your program in Win7? You can find that if you right click on your project's name and click Properties.

Answer (score 7):

It is a specific setting of your Eclipse IDE, you can find it in preferences under Java Compiler:

[image]

just disable it and everything will be fine :)

Comment: -1, needs more freehand circles, and another -1 for no drop shadow. +1 for being the correct answer, another +1 for freehand highlighting, and another +1 because I upvoted you.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, go to **Window** --> **Preferences**, and then navigate the tree menu to **Java** --> **Compiler** --> **Errors/Warnings**.  Under the **Code Style** section you should see an option for *Unqualified access to instance field*.  Change the option to "Ignore".

I imagine this option was not set to "Ignore" in your older setup which is why you weren't seeing the warnings.